# Variation of Parameters to solve

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Told to solve $y''-2y'+y=e^xcos(x)$ using variation of parameters method. Solution then uses Wronskian, $W$, as $e^x \begin{vmatrix}1 & x\\
1 & 1+x
\end{vmatrix}$ which I understand. However, the next step is that $W\begin{bmatrix}c'_{1}\\c'_{2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\cos(x)\end{bmatrix}$ which I don't understand at all. Obviously comes out as the right answer for $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ as the coefficients of the two solutions of the homogeneous equation but I am not sure how they knew it was $0$ and $cos(x)$. If anyone could explain this step that would be great thanks!

Comment: I think the system should actually be
$$W\begin{bmatrix} c_1' \\ c_2' \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \color{red}{e^x}\cos(x) \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

We are given

$$y''-2y'+y= g(x) = e^x \cos(x)$$

Finding the complementary solution

$$y_c(x) = e^x(c_1 + c_2 x)$$

Thus

$$y_1(x) = e^x, ~~~~y_2(x) = x e^x$$

The Wronskian of these two functions is

$$W(y_1, y_2) = \begin{vmatrix} e^x & x e^x \\ e^x & e^x(x+1) \end{vmatrix} = e^{2x}$$

Using [*VoP*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx), we have

$$y_p(x) = -y_1\int \dfrac{y_2~ g}{W}~dx + y_2 \int \dfrac{y_1~ g}{W}~dx$$

This is

$$y_p(x) =  -e^x \int \dfrac{x e^x( e^x \cos(x))}{e^{2x}}~dx + x e^x \int \dfrac{e^x(e^x \cos(x))}{e^{2x}}~dx$$

Can you proceed? You should get

$$y_p(x) = -e^x \cos(x)$$

The final solution is

$$y(x) = y_c(x) + y_p(x) = e^x(c_1 + c_2 x - \cos(x))$$

**Update** Maybe the derivation of this process is causing issues. For the DEQ

$$y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) = g(x)$$

Suppose $y_1(x), y_2(x)$ are two linearly independent solutions to  homogeneous and $W(y_1, y_2) \ne 0$.

We seek to determine two functions $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$ such that

$$y_p(x) = u_1(x) y_1(x) + u_2(x) y_2(x)$$

To determine two functions $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$ uniquely, we need to impose two independent conditions.

First, we shall require $y_p(x)$ above be a solution and second

$$u_1'(x) y_1 + u_2'(x) y_2 = 0$$

We thus have

$$u_1' y_1 + u_2' y_2 = 0 \\ u_1' y_1' + u_2' y_2' = g$$

This can be compactly written as

$$W\begin{bmatrix} u_1' \\ u_2' \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ e^x \cos(x) \end{bmatrix}$$

Lastly, this is solved as I show in the answer.

This can be extended to [*higher order non-homogenous DEQs*](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-method-of-variation-of-parameters-for-higher-order-nonho).

Comment: Yeah I don't understand how the particular solution $y_p$ that you are choosing works. Is it just a memorisable formula that it is equal to $(-y_1)$ times the integral of y2 times the solution all over the wronskian + the other integral etc

Comment: But in particular I want to understand this solution, when the solution sets the it up as a system of matrices how do we know to choose $0$ and $cos(x)$?

Comment: It is like ive written above.$e^x$ and $xe^x$ are $y_1$ and $y_2$ like you say and then you make the wronskian a matrix as i have done above and get the system as above where I don't understand how it is derived. Solving this system and then integrating $c'_1$ and $c'_2$ gives $y=c_1*y_1+c_2*y_2$ which is equal to the particular integral

Comment: Great thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering your side question about how to find solutions for linear ODE, you can read first my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3431378/399263.

Here the roots of the characteristic equation $r^2-2r+1=0$ are $r=1$ with multiplicity $m=2$.

The general solution of the homogeneous ODE is then $y_c=(ax+b)e^x$

The RHS is $e^x\cos(x)$ which is associated to roots $(1\pm i)$, since these roots do not collide with the one of the homogeneous ODE, we can search for a particular solution of the form $y_p(x)=c\,e^x\cos(x)+d\,e^x\sin(x)$, i.e. same degree than RHS (=cst).

After reporting in the ODE, you find $c=-1,d=0$ therefore $y_p(x)=-e^x\cos(x)$.